# What is the basis to reject/accept the flag if the flagged content is edited by user?

Tags: discussion, support, declined-flags

I found one question and which contains some personal details like the user name, password and IP address to an particular server.  I flagged the question to help prevent someone trying to hacked the server.  The moderators reviewed that question a long time after I flagged it, but by that time the user had edited his question and removed his personal details.

The end resdult is the moderator declined my flag, so I have lost one flag. I don't think that is a great way to evaluate the flag after long time or take action based on the current data because when we flagged one question we can't remove that flag until the moderators are reviewed.

I'm added my flag and the moderators replay below

> user shared personal details including username & password ,he may get hacked – White Maskers Oct 12 at 5:53
>   declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

I got this replay after a long time and then I check that question I can see that user removed his personal details.

**sorry for responding after along time**

i'm added some codes similar with his old code "

> @FindBy(how=How.NAME,using="username")
>    @CacheLookup
>       WebElement username;
>       @FindBy(how=How.NAME,using="password")"

,
in is old code he shared the original username and password instead of  username and password and he gives the ip address to his server too.which  similar to the code below ,

> WebDriver
>   driver=BrowserFactory.startBrowser("firefox","54.68.159.876/docmgr");

so an experienced tester can easily hack his server using this  details.

Comment: How long is "a long time".  You flagged it a month ago based on what info you provided here.  But when did the moderator decline your flag?

Comment: to find out when the flag was declined simply hover the mouse over word "declined" at your [meta-tag:flag-history] page (you can do the same for helpful and disputed flags to find when these were actioned)

Comment: AFAIK Mods only see the current revision in the flag queue so they may have seen here was no PPI there and declined it.  If that was the case then the ball was dropped.  They should go to the post and check the revision history to make sure that there was PPI.  It also allows them to remove it from the revision history if there was.

Comment: @NathanOliver we do check previous revisions. If nothing's immediately obvious in the post I check when it was flagged against the last edited time to see if it could have been edited since the flag. In this case we (I was the other moderator Undo's referring to) checked the revision history.

Answer (score 6):

This was a whole month ago, but I'll try to reconstruct what probably happened: I looked through the revision history and didn't see what you were talking about. Then I asked another moderator ([link for those who can see it](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/5293?m=33556561#33556561)), who *also* couldn't see what you were referencing.

I *think* I see it now, but it took a solid two minutes looking at the post to find it.

In the future, try to be more specific in those flags.

Comment: Would editing that stuff out before/after flagging help so you guys can see it in its own revision?

Comment: @NathanOliver That definitely helps. It also gives us a quicker way to redact the previous revisions.

Comment: @undo sorry for responding after along time,i'm adding some codes similar with his old code